# I'm getting an error when using the Donut Model: Input Type and Bias type should be the same

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, ocr, donut

I'm trying to extract text from image using the [Donut Model](https://github.com/clovaai/donut) which is an Image Parser. It seems that the input image is not in the proper format.

I'm getting an error that says:
`RuntimeError: Input type (float) and bias type (c10::BFloat16)` should be the same
on this line:

`output = model.inference(image=image, prompt="<s_cord-v2>")`

Here is my entire code:

```py
    from donut import DonutModel 
    from PIL import Image 
    import torch 

    model = DonutModel.from_pretrained("naver-clova-ix/donut-base- 
    finetuned-cord-v2") 

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model.half()      
        device = torch.device("cuda")      
        model.to(device)  
    else:      
        model.encoder.to(torch.bfloat16) model.eval()  

    image = Image.open("testfolder/test1.jpg").convert("RGB") 
    output = model.inference(image=image, prompt="<s_cord-v2>") 
    output
```

I understand that image is not in the right format, but how would I go about fixing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the error by removing the else-clause in your code. I suppose you have a CPU and bfloat16 is probably wrong for the model. This code works fine for me:

```
from donut import DonutModel 
from PIL import Image 
import torch 

model = DonutModel.from_pretrained("naver-clova-ix/donut-base-finetuned-cord-v2") 

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model.half()      
    device = torch.device("cuda")      
    model.to(device)  

model.eval()  
image = Image.open("./donut/misc/sample_image_cord_test_receipt_00004.png").convert("RGB") 
output = model.inference(image=image, prompt="<s_cord-v2>") 
output
```